# why the two chart are automatically $C^{\infty}$ - compatible?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

In textbook it is written that

Two chart $(U, \phi: U \to \mathbb{R}^n), (V, \psi: V\to \mathbb{R}^n )$ of a  topological manifold are $C^{\infty}$ compatible  if the two map
$$\phi \circ \psi^{-1} : \psi(U \cap V) \to \phi(U \cap V), \; \psi \circ \phi^{-1} : \phi(U \cap V) \to \psi(U \cap V)$$
are $C^\infty$.

> If $U \cap V$ empty ,then the  two chart  are automatically $C^{\infty}$ - compatible

**My confusion** : Im not getting  why two chart  are automatically $C^{\infty}$ - compatible ?

**My thinking** : If $U \cap V = \emptyset$.Then $\phi \circ \psi^{-1} : \psi(U \cap V) \to \phi(U \cap V) \implies \phi \circ \psi^{-1}:\emptyset \to \emptyset $

$\phi \circ \psi^{-1}= \emptyset$

I think  there are no such functions  exist  which map $\emptyset$ to $\emptyset$

Also ,this doesn't make sense because $\psi(U \cap V)$ and  $\phi(U \cap V)$ are closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$  if $U \cap V =\emptyset$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $U \cap V = \emptyset$, then $\phi(U \cap V)$ and $\psi(U \cap V)$ are both the empty set in $\mathbb R^n$.  So they are open in $\mathbb R^n$.

The map $\phi \circ \psi^{-1}: \emptyset \rightarrow \emptyset$ (which is itself the empty set) is a diffeomorphism.  It is smooth because it is differentiable at every point of $\emptyset$.  Its inverse is smooth as well.